# Cannot get example working for RabbitPy

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rabbitpy

I cannot seem to get the code running - I've been using Pika and keen to try out this thread safe and possibly neater version.

```
import rabbitpy

with rabbitpy.Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f') as conn:
    with conn.channel() as channel:
        queue = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, 'example')

        # Exit on CTRL-C
        try:
            # Consume the message
            for message in queue:
                message.pprint(True)
                message.ack()

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print 'Exited consumer'
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newshift.py", line 3, in <module>
    with rabbitpy.Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f') as conn:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Connection'
```

My systems settings are:

```
numpy==1.11.2
pamqp==1.6.1
pandas==0.19.0
pika==0.10.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.7
rabbitpy==1.0.0
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.3
```

---

```
dir(rabbitpy)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

Somehow the classes are not seen when loading in the module

Original issue was caused by .pyc files hanging around, but new error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newshift.py", line 15, in <module>
    print 'Exited consumer' 
  File "/home/brett/code/SimpleConsumers/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rabbitpy/connection.py", line 149, in __exit__
    raise exc_val
rabbitpy.exceptions.AMQPNotFound: <pamqp.specification.Channel.Close object at 0x7f39a91da7d0>
```

Comment: Do you wrap it in the class? If you have a class called `class RabbitPy(object)`, you need to call it like `from rabbitpy import RabbitPy as rp`, and then try to use connection like so: `rp.Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f')`. I've had the similar issue when I was testing my setup.

Comment: did you use name `rabbitpy` for you file (`rabbitpy.py`) or folder ? Then now you import this file instead original  module. Check `print( rabbitpy.__file__ )`

Comment: @furas I updated my question now. I did indeed have this naming issue - doh, but not cannot seem to get the other libraries working.

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't work for me - I got the same error. But I have no problem with examples on https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

Comment: I tried sending with `pika` and receive with `rabbitpy` and it (almost) works if  `rabbitpy` uses queue with name `hello` instead of `example` (because `pika` use name `hello`). I think `rabbitpy` doesn't work because it tries to use non-existing queue with name `example` but it doesn't create it first. Pika always create queue `hello` (in both examples - for sending and for receiving - read tutorial) so it always works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rabbitpy.exceptions.AMQPNotFound: <pamqp.specification.Channel.Close`

I think `rabbitpy` gives this error because it tries to connect to non-existing `queue` with name `example`

```
queue = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, 'example')
```

but `rabbitpy` doesn't create this queue if it doesn't exist yet.

I checked [examples with pika](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) and they work because `pika` creates queue (with name `hello`) when it doesn't exists so it can send and receive from this queue safely.

`pika` automatically create queue in both situations - when you send or receive message.

---

You can check existing queues in rabbitmq with command (on Linux)

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

ie. result

```
Listing queues ...
celery  3
hello   0
...done.
```

---

If I send message with `pika` then I can receive it with `rabbitpy` because `pika` creates queue if it doesn't exist and then `rabbitpy` can safely use this queue.

---

It seams you have to use `queue.declare()` to create queue if it doesn't exist.

```
import rabbitpy

with rabbitpy.Connection('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/%2f') as conn:
    with conn.channel() as channel:
        queue = rabbitpy.Queue(channel, 'example')
        queue.declare() # <---
```

Comment: My bad, I was expecting a more verbose error message. Thanks though!